# What is the meaning of 'default size' from MSDN DBCC SHRINK FILE instruction?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, msdn

From MSDN's note

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql
>
> You can reduce the default size of an empty file by using DBCC
>   SHRINKFILE target_size. For example, if you create a 5-MB file and
>   then shrink the file to 3 MB while the file is still empty, the
>   **default file size** is set to 3 MB. This applies only to empty files
>   that have never contained data.

I have never seen term called 'Default File Size' except of the file size of Model Database, Are they referencing initial size of the data file, or something else that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES,the default size here means size of file when it was created..It can be see further down in docs

> The default size is the size specified when the file was created.